# How to add multiple binding port to Pure-Ftpd

Tags: pureftpd

Can I add multiple Bind port to PureFtpD on Ubuntu machine?
I could change the binding port editing the /etc/pure-ftpd/Bind file. But I cannot understand how set an additional port. I tried to add a new line in Bind file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that pure-ftpd does not support multiple `Bind` statements in the configuration. It also did not work by specifying multiple bind options on the command line `-S`.

As a workaround, it can be done using iptables `DNAT` rule like the following:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1021 -j DNAT --to-destination :21
```

This rule enables you to receive FTP traffic on both ports: 21 (default one) and 1021.